# Ruby - loop through array

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops

In a form I have a list of products from database and every product has these items in the form:

```
= text_field_tag 'item['+product.id.to_s+'][]'
= text_field_tag 'item_value1['+product.id.to_s+'][]'
= text_field_tag 'item_value2['+product.id.to_s+'][]'
```

I am trying to loop over the array and get all those (**item**, **item_value1**, **item_value2**) this way:

```
params[:item].each_with_index do |val, index|
  puts "#{val[0]} => #{val[1]}"
end
```

and the output is like:

```
191359 => [""]
191361 => [""]
191360 => ["15"]
191212 => [""]
191210 => ["9"]
248974 => [""]
191209 => [""]
190920 => [""]
190919 => [""]
190921 => [""]
```

But, how to get all data for the respective products? Something like

```
puts "item: #{item}, item_value1: #{item_value1}, item_value2: #{item_value2}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three parameters here `item`, `item_value1` and `item_value2`. Iterating over item will give you values from parameter items only and not from `intem_value1` and `item_value2`. If the indexes of these 3 parameters are relative, then you can play with index as in your code

```
params[:item].each_with_index do |val, index|
  puts "#{params[:item_value1][index]} => #{params[:item_value1][index]}"
end
```